# Reflection Class.getDeclaredFields() is not retrieving anything on Android

Tags: java, android, reflection, icu

I have an instance of class `android.icu.util.TimeZone` which actually instance of `android.icu.impl.OlsonTimeZone`. I need to retrieve a field of transitions using reflection. But getDeclaredFields retrieves only one static field. How could it be, if during debuging I see lots of fields in this class?

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Kiev");
try {
    Class<?> actionClass = Class.forName(tz.getClass().getName()/*, true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()*/); // Also have tried with SystemClassLoader
    Field[] allFields = actionClass.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : allFields) {
            Log.d("field:", field.getName());
        }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image: Instance members]

[image: What reflection is retrieved]

When I try to retrieve `transitionTimes64` directly I'v got `NoSuchFieldException No field transitionTimes in class Landroid/icu/impl/OlsonTimeZone; (declaration of 'android.icu.impl.OlsonTimeZone' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar`

Comment: android does no longer allow for reflections like that, so I don't think you will be able to skip it, you can check if there is private native method named like `getDeclaredFields0` and call it via reflections, but its probably only on normal JVM

Comment: @GotoFinal Since when it is not supported? There lots of examples people use reflection in android. Even in androidx library.

Comment: not every reflection is not supported, just the ones trying to get inside internal classes: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces it might be your case